Windows gradlew quarkusDev - the encoding of all non-ASCII characters in the log output and even System.out is broken
I'm a Quarkus newcomer.
I faced with strange encoding bug - log output of my app contains '???' instead a national chars...
For tests this issue I added a simple System.out.println("my national chars here: йцукенгфывапр")
Then, I do next tests:

Windows (CMD): java -jar quarkus-run.jur - the all is OK
Windows CMD): gradlew quarkusDev - encoding issue
WSL:     java -jar quarkus-run.jur - the all is OK
WSL:     gradlew quarkusDev - the all is OK

Also, I found that additional quarkusDev parameter in build.gradle.kts partially fix this problem:
tasks.quarkusDev {
    jvmArgs = ("-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8").split(" ")
}

After it, Windows: gradlew quarkusDev - the System.out is OK, but all log trace|debug|info outputs still broken

Powershell is going to give you better encodings support. But what goes chcp give in cmd.exe/
